# Repeated Measures Anova with afex - array extend not equal?

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I try to calculate a repeated measures anova with afex. I have the following data

```
    # A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Subject, MemSetSize, Lure [4]
  Subject MemSetSize Lure      Distance meanRT
    <int>      <int> <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>
1       1          3 InSetLure Clo        452.
2       1          3 InSetLure Dist       400.
3       1          3 Random    Dist       412.
4       1          5 InSetLure Clo        553.
5       1          5 InSetLure Dist       533.
6       1          5 Random    Dist       490.
```

SetSize 3 Lvl is 3,5,7
Lure Cat 2 Levels & Distance 2 Levels-> I want to analyze the effects of Lure & Distance seprately and their interaction. Therfore I have this Anova

MemSetSize (3)x Lures(2) x Distance (2)

DV is the Reaction time.

is specified the afex ez anova like this

```
anova_hyp2a_Lure <- aov_ez("Subject","meanRT", hyp2a_lure_RT,
      within = c("MemSetSize","Lure","Distance"), anova_table = list(es="pes"))
```

I got this error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to Array extend
Additional Warning
In aov(formula(paste(dv.escaped, "~", paste(c(between.escaped, within.escaped),  :
  Error() model is singular
```

I don't really know whats wrong, both Variables are marked as factors with 2 Levels, and the design (for that analysis) is fully crossed, there are no missing values. Is it because afex don't realize the combined factors?

What das this Error about the array extend means? I didn't find smth related to an anova.

thanks guys!

regards

*J

Comment: I don't know how `aov_ez` works, but `Subject` has only one level and it is included in your model. I suspect that is causing the singularity error.

Comment: yeah but thats ok, that are the observations for each subject - it works fine without the "Distance" factor. I think it is related to that.